# MAAS Power-on problem IDRAC IPMI 2.0

Tags: networking, server, power-management, maas, pxe

I'm currently having a problem in getting MaaS (v1.7) to properly provision a Dell PowerEdge R630 server. The MaaS vm itself is able to detect the server automatically, and once the dell server boots using PXE, the installation of Ubuntu (my target OS) begins as you would normally expect. However, after a few minutes (during Ubuntu's installation), the server shuts down (I'm assuming this is part of the provisioning process?) and then MaaS fails to power it back up. As such, Ubuntu fails to get installed and provisioning comes to a halt.

The dell servers use IPMI 2.0 as a management interface, and the configuration is correctly captured by MaaS (as far as I can tell). The official docs state that power-on issues might be caused by desynchronization of system clocks but this is something that I already checked. As such, I'm currently unsure about how to approach this issue, but I'll be appreciative if anyone can shed some light on what could be causing MaaS to be unable to properly power-on/off the connected servers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had to turn on IPMI in the Network settings on the iDRAC for this to work:

```
iDRAC -> iDRAC Settings -> Network/Security -> Network -> IPMI Settings
[x]Enable IPMI Over LAN
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation. Attempting to add a poweredge server and having MAAS fail to power the server back on after a reboot.

Reading this whitepaper from Dell:
https://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/Deploying_Workloads_With_Juju_And_MAAS-14.04LTS-Edition.pdf

it looks like this may be because I don't have virtual media set to auto-attached, the above pdf states:

`All servers must be equipped with out-of-band management such as an iDRAC or a BMC controller, as they will be powered on and off via IPMI commands, so be sure to turn on IPMI over LAN. If using an iDRAC, virtual media must be set to auto-attached, otherwise the OS provisioning process will fail.`

This is because this option seems disabled without the license, and I'm trying to get by without purchasing an iDRAC license.

Has anyone else on this thread been able to commission an iDRAC enabled server without a license?